# call function on my constructor after Object.create

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function action (){}

action.prototype = {
  run : function (){
    alert("run");
  },

  jump : function (){
    alert("jump");
  }
}

var person = Object.create(action.prototype, {
    // call run and jump function here.
});
```

3 Question

1.how do i call the run and jump function at person i create.

2.can my person function be self invoked ? aka LIFE

3.how to make my code "syntactic sugar" ?

Comment: 1. `person.jump()` and `person.run()` ? 2. person is not a function. It's an object. Not sure what you mean by " person function be self invoked" . 3. No idea what you mean here either. The whole setup is a bit strange. Maybe if you explain the original problem you are trying to solve, we could help you better.

Comment: Thank for reply , sorry i am still learning , my intention is to create a 2 function to use by other object. well someone tell me my code should be more syntactic sugar , not sure about it. so i ask.

Comment: is there any way i can make person as function but also use the action function ?

Comment: I don't see why `action` needs to be a function at all. Maybe you want something like this: `var actions = {run: ..., jump: ...}; function Person() {} ; Object.assign(Person.prototype, actions); var aPerson = new Person(); aPerson.run();`. Again, it's not quite clear what result you actually want to get.

Comment: and i call person.jump(); before as well , i have Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .